# Knowing If a Function is Supported in OpenGL es 2.0

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

Is http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/ the end all be all, or is there another source that tells you exactly which functions are supported by OpenGL ES 2.0?

For example, is `glUniformXY()` supported by OpenGL ES 2.0? I don't see it on that page but it doesn't make since for it not to be.

Comment: What's 'glUniformXY' in this context? Per your linked page all the normal glUniforms are defined — look under 'u'.

Comment: You are correct. The question still stands though is the link above the only supported API by systems that claim to support OpenGL ES 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to lookup function declarations directly in the header file: http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/api/2.0/gl2.h It is much faster.

If the system support OpenGL ES2.0 all those functions are defined and should conform to the standard. If you want vendor specific methods or behaviours you need to query for OpenGL extensions and then dynamically resolve the functions

Comment: The header file is a much better answer to the actual question because it's a formal specification, but when just looking things up quickly I favour the reference card — http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/reference_cards/OpenGL-ES-2_0-Reference-card.pdf (and GLSL is on there too)

Comment: Good addition to the conversation.